# Backup restore SQLite core data iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, core-data, backup

I'm working on a project where I create a instance of my app sqllite file and set it up so the user can email the backup file to his/her own email. I've seen this done on iStudiezPro and it works magically.

I can get the email to open up the app file and restore, the problem is that for the persistence store to update the app would have to reload. 
When coming back to the app I do this:

```
[persistentStoreCoordinator release];
persistentStoreCoordinator = nil;

[managedObjectContext release];
managedObjectContext = nil;

[primaryUserManagedObject release];
primaryUserManagedObject = nil;

[self managedObjectContext];
```

I just need to find a way for the app to rebuild the core data stack while the app is running. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to just save the context and then copy the store file to the documents folder using standard fileManager methods. If you make sure that there are no ongoing Core Data operations, I don't think you will have any problems with corruption.

If you want extra protection, before you copy, release and nil the managedObject context and then the persistent store coordinator. When the copy is done, rebuild the stack. There is no reason to restart the app itself. You probably will have to create a dedicated object to manage the Core Data stack so that it can be turned on and off.

Comment: Essentially, that is what I am trying to do. After switching out the sqllite file, I try to reinitialize my managedObjectContext in my app delegate, keep in mind that in my entire app I am referencing the primaryUserManagedObject and managedObjectContext from my appDelegate. The problem I have is that I don't understand how to rebuild my Core Data stack.

Comment: If you use the default Core Data template in Xcode, merely accessing the managedObjectContext will trigger the initialize of the Core Data stack because the context is created by the accessor if it does not exist, that in turn triggers the initialization an managed object model, a persistent store coordinator and persistent store files. So, if you nil out everything and then access them again, they should reinitialize with fresh instances. I think. I haven't done it that way. Leaning to build the stack is not that hard if you look at the template. It shows you pretty much everything.

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded a sample app that provides backup and restore capabilities a number of different ways, including local backups, copy backups to and from iCloud, email backups, import from email, and file copy via iTunes. See link below for video demonstrating these capabilities and you can download the sample apps from the site.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/sample-apps-explanations/backup-files/